# Single quoted literal value fails Antlr lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a lexer rule that defines single-quoted literal string as

```
L_S_STRING  : '\'' (('\'' '\'') | ('\\' '\'') | ~('\''))* '\''
```

It fails one particular case:

```
'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z\\''
```

The problem is really with the last two single quotes. If I added a space in between, it worked. Or I could use two single quotes to end and it worked too, e.g.

```
'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z'''
```

I am not sure if it has something to do with having a non-greedy operator which caused the first-match of ('\'' '\'')? If so, I don't see how the last version could have worked.

In any event, could someone help please?

UPDATE - I am not able to reproduce it outside of the full grammar. This may be a red herring.

UPDATE - I missed some important context so I posted another question here [Antlr4: single quote rule fails when there are escape chars plus carriage return, new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465057/antlr4-single-quote-rule-fails-when-there-are-escape-chars-plus-carriage-return)

Comment: Can you please tell more about your syntax? How the characters are escaped and  the meaning of two single quotes, which strings are valid and which are not.

Comment: Please add a MCVE that demonstrates what you describe: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce that. Given the following grammar:

```
lexer grammar Test;

L_S_STRING  : '\'' (('\'' '\'') | ('\\' '\'') | ~('\''))* '\'';
OTHER       : . ;
```

which can be tested as follows:

```
String source = "A'yyyy-MM-dd\\\\'T\\\\'HH:mm:ss\\\\'Z\\\\''B";

Test lexer = new Test(CharStreams.fromString(source));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
tokens.fill();

for (Token t : tokens.getTokens()) {
    System.out.printf("%-15s %s\n", Test.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()), t.getText());
}
```

will print:

```
OTHER           A
L_S_STRING      'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z\\''
OTHER           B
EOF             <EOF>
```