# Antlr4: single quote rule fails when there are escape chars plus carriage return, new line

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar as such:

```
grammar Testquote;
program : (Line ';')+ ;
Line: L_S_STRING ;
L_S_STRING  : '\'' (('\'' '\'') | ('\\' '\'') | ~('\''))* '\''; // Single quoted string literal
L_WS        : L_BLANK+ -> skip ;   // Whitespace
fragment L_BLANK : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') ;
```

This grammar--and the `L_S_STRING` in particular--seems working fine with vanilla inputs like:

```
'ab';
'cd';
```

However, it fails with this input:

```
'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z\\'';
'cd';
```

Yet works when I changed the first line to either 
`'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z''';` or
`'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z\\' '`;

I sorta can see why the parser may choose this failed route. But is there some way I can tell it to choose differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ANTLR4 docs, both lexer and parser rules are **greedy**, thus matching **as much input as they can**. In your case:

```
'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss\\'Z\\'';
                               ^^^
'cd';
```

Your grammar is somewhat ambiguous - the characters I've highlighted can be interpreted as `\'` `'` or as `\` `''`. See how it works.

Without `'cd'`, lexer matches a string because it's a valid string for your grammar, highlighted characters are matched as `\'` `'`. But since lexer is greedy, it will use the aforementioned ambiguity to match unwanted input at first possibility, such as adding another unescaped `'` somewhere later.

This ambiguity is caused by possibility of backslash being either normal character or escape character. The common solution for removing such ambiguity is a rule for **escaping the backslash itself**: `\\`, also you need to **not match it as a normal character**.

Alternatively, you may want to deal with ambiguity in a different way. If you want to prioritize `\'` over `''`, you should write:

```
L_S_STRING  : '\'' ( ('\'\'') | ('\\'+ ~'\\') | ~('\'' | '\\') )* '\'' ;
```

It will work for your input.

By the way, you can shorten your code for L_WS:

```
L_WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Yes the version you laid out here worked for my test cases, even though it prevents the escape character being the sole input. So I am thinking hard on what you said before that - "... a rule for escaping the backslash itself: \\, also you need to not match it as a normal character." That would be an ideal solution. However, if that were the case, I wonder if my test case was in error, since the two escapes yields into one, then I still need one to escape the single quote within the input. Am I correct? Regardless, thank you so much for your detailed answer!

Comment: The rule for escaping single quotes and backslashes will be `'\'' ('\\\'' | '\\\\' | ~('\\' | '\''))* '\''`. It does not handle pairs of single quotes though, but there's no need for it.